# Get a text beside a qoute using regex

Tags: regex

This is the text

"This is a quote"

The output must be

"This
quote"

So what it does is getting all the word that is beside a qoute

So far this is my regex code

```
"\s*(.*?)\s*"
```

But I am getting all the string inside the quote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to match word just next to or before double quote:

```
"\s*\S+|\S+\s*"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xV2oE2/1)

Your regex `"\s*(.*?)\s*"` will match all the text between quotes and optional whitespaces.